# Changing user group in onUserBeforeSave of user profile plugin doesn't work

Tags: user-groups

I added following code in onUserBeforeSave of user profile plugin(plugins/user/profile/profile.php):

```
    if ($isnew)
    {
        if (!strcasecmp($data['role'], 'group0'))
        {
            $data['groups'] = array(10);
        }
        elseif (!strcasecmp($data['role'], 'group1'))
        {
            $data['groups'] = array(11);
        }

        JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(print_r($user, true));
        JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(print_r($data, true));       
    }
```

The print_r results show the $data has been modified successfully, but in the end, the new user added to database still in old group, which is 'Registered'.

I am not sure what's the reason for this. And how can I achieve overriding default user groups. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't edit user data in `onUserBeforeSave` and `onUserAfterSave` event. This is just a copy of what will/was saved. It would be better to:

- use `onUserAfterSave` event
- get user object after save `$user = JFactory::getUser($user_id)` where `$user_id` is id of a user you want to modify
- modify user groups like this `$user->groups = Array($new_user_group)`
- save user `$user->save()`